# How to Set A Webpage in gray scale color Mode while clicking a Button

Tags: javascript, css

In my website I'm using a lot of images, tables, and fonts with different colors inside one div tag. When the user clicks a button the whole webpage should change to a grayscale color mode. In that mode the user should still be able to use the page.

In IE I'm using

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1);
```

Which works fine, but it's not working in Mozilla Firefox.

I found [this link](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html). They only provide a script for converting an image into grayscale. But I need to convert a full `div` tag, containing many things like images, fonts & so on.

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: I think you must use css and different set of images(for b/w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using canvas :

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html

or use a separate css 
something like this :
body class="color"
body class="bw"

and define "bw" in your  css

for all the images you change the source with javascript :
src=foo.jpg
src=foo_bw.jpg

Comment: <canvas width="500" height="500" runat="server"></canvas>

Comment: canvas
        {
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s;
            -ms-transition: all 1s;
            -o-transition: all 1s;
            -moz-transition: all 1s;
            opacity: 0;
        }

Comment: function greyImages() {var ctx=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getContext('2d'),img = document.getElementById('cvs-src'),    imageData, px, length, i = 0,red, green, blue, grey;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 500);
                px = imageData.data;
                length = px.length;
                for (; i < length; i += 4) {grey = 0.3 * px[i] + 0.59 * px[i + 1] + 0.11 * px[i + 2];
                    px[i] = px[i + 1] = px[i + 2] = grey;
                }ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);}})();

Comment: ####******(These are my image conversions Script,Css,Html Codings. Working Fine IN IE and Mozilla(Conversion Working With Single Image).But I Need A Script for single Div tag or Whole WEB Page.)*****###

Comment: that is what I am telling .. Use a separate css that defines the new b/w(gray scale) colors . there doesn't seem be a one function conversion.